# Ошибка при вызове функции PHP

Tags: php

PHP ругается

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/search/translit.php on line 4`

при вызове функции:

```
function unanslite($st) { 
    // Сначала заменяем "многосимвольные" фонемы. 
    $st=strtr($st,array( 
        'yo'=>'ё', 'zh'=>'ж', 'cz'=>'ц', 'ch'=>'ч', 'sh'=>'ш',

        'shh'=>'щ', '``'=>'ъ', 'y`'=>'ы', '`'=>'ь', 'e`'=>'э', 'yu'=>'ю', 'ya'=>'я', 
        'YO'=>'Ё', 'ZH'=>'Ж', 'CZ'=>'Ц', 'CH'=>'Ч', 'SH'=>'Ш',

        'SHH'=>'Щ', '``'=>'ъ', 'Y`'=>'Ы', '`'=>'ь', 'E`'=>'Э', 'YU'=>'Ю', 'YA'=>'Я') 
    );
    // Затем - "односимвольные"  
    $st=strtr($st,'abvgdezijklmnoprstufh','абвгдезийклмнопрстуфх'); 
    $st=strtr($st,'ABVGDEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFh','АБВГДЕЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХ'); 
    return $st; 
} // Функция отвечающая за транслит
```

на открывающуюся скобку. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: На код приведенный в вопросе, с учетом того, что я уже сказал в своем ответе, php не выдает ошибок. Выложите содержимое файла `translit.php` полностью, вероятно где-то выше в коде вы забыли поставить { или }. Если фаил очень большой, то его лучше выложить, например, на [pastebin.com][1]

[1]: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Я бы еще вынесла чисто для наглядности:  
<pre><code>$arr=array('yo'=>'ё', 'zh'=>'ж', 'cz'=>'ц', 'ch'=>'ч', 'sh'=>'ш', 'shh'=>'щ', '``'=>'ъ', 'y`'=>'ы', '`'=>'ь', 'e`'=>'э', 'yu'=>'ю', 'ya'=>'я', 'YO'=>'Ё', 'ZH'=>'Ж', 'CZ'=>'Ц', 'CH'=>'Ч', 'SH'=>'Ш', 'SHH'=>'Щ', '``'=>'ъ', 'Y`'=>'Ы', '`'=>'ь', 'E`'=>'Э', 'YU'=>'Ю', 'YA'=>'Я');  
$st=strtr($st,$arr); </code></pre>

Comment: Пользуйтесь нормальной средой разработки Eclipse, Netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function unanslite("$st") {
```

замените на

```
function unanslite($st) {
```